# How to plot Higher time frame indicator using end-of-day value of Lower time frame indicator ? [Pine Script] /[Tradingview]

Tags: trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, indicator

I have written a script (Pine script / Tradingview) like this :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Normalized (ATR - wise) Relative strength of a stock compared to an index (daily close comparison)", "Normalized (ATR - wise) Relative strength of a stock",precision = 2)
//Input
comparativeTickerId = input.symbol("VNINDEX",title = "Comparative Symbol" )
smoothing = input.string(title="Smoothing", defval="RMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])
lengthFastMA = input.int(5,minval=1, title="Fast MA")
lengthSlowMA = input.int(25,minval=1, title="Slow MA")

//Calculation

baseSymbol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", close)   
fixSymbolBar = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1],barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on) 
atr_baseSymbol = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.atr(25)) 
normalizeSymbolBar = (baseSymbol-fixSymbolBar)/atr_baseSymbol

comparativeSymbol = request.security(comparativeTickerId, "60", close)   
fixComparativeSymbolbar = request.security(comparativeTickerId, "D", close[1],barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)   // correct
atrComparativeSymbol = request.security(comparativeTickerId,"60",ta.atr(25))  
normalizeComparativeSymbol = (comparativeSymbol - fixComparativeSymbolbar)/atrComparativeSymbol

ma_function(source, length) =>
    switch smoothing
        "RMA" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        => ta.wma(source, length)
    
res = (normalizeSymbolBar - normalizeComparativeSymbol)*100

 //plot

plot(res,style = plot.style_columns, color = res > 0 ? color.blue : color.orange)
plot(ma_function(res,lengthFastMA), color = ma_function(res,lengthFastMA) > 0 ? #0c5847 : color.red, title = "Fast MA", linewidth = 2)
plot(ma_function(res,lengthSlowMA), style =  plot.style_area, title = 'Slow MA', color = color.gray)
```

In short, this indicator calculate the different between the normalized return of a stock compared to that of an index.
Now i want to write an indicator on daily time frame using the end-of-day value of ta.ema(res,lengthFastMA) on 60 mins time frame to plot. For example, lets say the value of ta.ema(res,lengthFastMA) of 23 pm June 30th 2022 bar on 60 mins timeframe is 50,  that makes the value of the indicator on daily time frame for June 30th 2022 is 50 too.

Anyone can help on this issue pls?. Thank you so much

Comment: I have solved this problem thanks to Pinecoder tele group, if anyone want the answear just contact me. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
my_timeframe = input.timeframe(title="Custom Timeframe", defval="1", group="Strategy parameters")
    
changed_data = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, my_timeframe, graph_data, gaps=barmerge.gaps_on)
    
plot(changed_data , title = "Your custom graph", color=color.orange)
```

For version 5: define timeframe input to allow customize from settings section, request security update with your timeframe that is different than deafult for your view, show graph.